# Flutter images overflow

Tags: html, flutter, dart, intellij-idea, overflow

I need help with the Flexible widget.

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding : EdgeInsets.all(20),
      child: RawMaterialButton(
          onPressed: onPressed,
          elevation: 4.0,
          fillColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
        child: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            appBar: PreferredSize(
                preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(30.0),
                child: AppBar(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
                  automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                  centerTitle: true,
                  title: Text(title),
                )
            ),
            body: Column(
              children: [
                Flexible(
                  child: Image.network(
                      link,
                      fit:BoxFit.fill
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0,10,0,10),
                  child: Divider(),
                ),
                Text(
                  type,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      wordSpacing: 1.0,
                      fontStyle: FontStyle.italic
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  "Prezzo: "+price.toString()+"€",
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

the method works because the image follows the size of the window, but if I make it too small the image disappears and gives me this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2i02M.png).

I have made several attempts but have not found a solution to the problem.

EDIT:
basically my panel looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5zxC.png) but if I try to make it too small it gives me this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aow2X.png).

Comment: It can be difficult to troubleshoot overflow issues without access to the full application. If you are using Android Studio, I recommend looking at the Flutter Inspector's Layout Explorer to see where your problems are.  Another option is to use Stack and Positioned elements instead of a Column since it seems that you want to put objects on top of each other.

Comment: Using stack element work to solve the error, but i want to put objects under each others, i upload an image that show the final result.

Comment: You can use Positioned objects to control placement above, below, left or to the right of each other.